# Is there a $parent equivalent in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngfor

In angularJS, inside an ng-repeat we could access the data using $parent. Is there an equivalent in Angular 7? Below is the scenario

My Model classes :-

```
export class Question {
  Sections : Array<Section>;
  IsArchived : boolean;
}

export class Section{
  Name : string;
}
```

HTML :-

```
<div *ngFor="let section of Question.Sections">
  {{section.Name}}
  <!--Want to access parent here-->
  <span *ngIf="$parent.IsArchived"> This is archived</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell you are trying to achieve in Angular 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent of $parent in angular as in angularjs however you can simply use the parent Object within the ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let section of Question.Sections">
  {{section.Name}}
  <span *ngIf="Question.IsArchived"> This is archived</span>
</div>
```